# Can't delete/remove more than one comment, after first comment I have to exit then re-enter Activity for other comments to be gone

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding a feature so that the user can delete their comment, which with the following code works fine, BUT it only deletes a comment once. Say that I open my `CommentActivity` and there I write 3 comments, and then I decide to delete all 3 or 2, so what happens is it allows me to remove 1 comment which gets **deleted** and **removed** right away, BUT the other ones I have to exit the `CommentActivity` and re-enter for the other comments that I tried deleting to be gone. I want to be able to delete ALL comments and for them to **be gone** right away.

Anyone can tell me why/how to fix it?

**CommentsActivity**

```
private void readComments() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                try {
                    comment.setComment(decrypt(comment.getComment(), mPassword));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mCommentList.add(comment);
                keysList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int index = keysList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mCommentList.remove(index);
                keysList.remove(index);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mCommentList, mPostId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        reference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
```